# Python - Compare files

Tags: python, file, comparison

I need to use a `get()` to select an object by comparing it with a FILE request:

My models:

```
class Work (models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(storage=OverwriteStorage(), upload_to=path)

class Group(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='group_list', null=True, blank=True)
```

I have tried: `var = mygroup.work_list.get(file=request.FILES['file'])`

With the **same file**: `Work matching query does not exist`

### EDIT :

I prefer in reality to compare the name of file but that doesn't works too:

```
var = mygroup.work_list.get(file__name=request.FILES['file'].name)
```

### EDIT2 :

It seems I can't make a request whith informations about file, I have tried with size `Join on field 'file' not permitted. Did you misspell 'size' for the lookup type?`I have the same message with name...

Comment: Even if you've got the same file saved against two instances of your model, they won't be identified as being the same unless you open them and compare the contents of the files...

Comment: I have tried with names and I can't too.. I edit !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found : `var = mygroup.work_list.get(file=path+'/'+request.FILES['file'].name)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try generating and storing a md5-hash of the file and compare with this key.

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but I don't know if my server would be ok with many users :) It is not possible simply wuth names ??